# Why is this rotation speed off by a factor of (1/2) in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, modeling

I'm modeling the earth's rotation on its axis. Since one complete  rotation of the earth on its axis is equal to

```
(2*Math.PI)
```

radians, I figured that I could calculate the earth's rotation per minute (per frame) as

```
(2*Math.PI)/(24*60)
```

. I'm currently rendering at 60FPS using the requestAnimationFrame() method, which implies that each second the program runs, I should be simulating one hour of actual earth rotation. I checked the javascript console in Chrome, and it is rendering at 60FPS. However, the simulation seems to be running twice as fast, i.e., every 12 seconds I get a complete rotation instead of every 24. If I change the expression to

```
(2*Math.PI)/(24*60*2)
```

, suddenly I get the correct rotation speed, and 24 seconds = 1 full rotation. I'm glad that I'm able to get the program to work, but it's bothersome that I don't understand why I need to multiply the expression by a factor of (1/2) for that to happen. Does anyone have any ideas why I might be getting this behavior? Thanks in advance.

The expression I'm using in my render function is

```
earth.rotation.y += (2*Math.PI)/(24*60*2)
```

.

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` uses the best frame time available for each frame, it can change slightly and modify the movement in few seconds.

1. I cannot explain your significantly stunning result, however what can be done when one needs a purely time-dependent movement is to multiply the movement by the time since last render :

   ```
   var lastDate = new Date();

   function render () {

       var now = new Date();
       var delay = now - lastDate;
       lastDate = now;

       earth.rotation.y += delay * your-rotation-coeff

       requestAnimationFrame( render );
       renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }
   ```
2. However `new Date()` is not the most precise javascript feature. It is `performance.now()`, [which is not available in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=high-resolution-time). So instead of writing all the previous four lines plus the fallback code, in three.js you can simply use the feature `Clock` that does all that and can be implemented much quicker :

   ```
   var clock = new THREE.Clock();

   function render () {

       earth.rotation.y += clock.getDelta() * your-rotation-coeff

       requestAnimationFrame( render );
       renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }
   ```

Comment: Correct and upvoted. A simpler approach is to use THREE clock, that has a getDelta function see https://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/core/Clock.js.html

Comment: I tried the approach above. The earth wouldn't render.